# Nextjs use b or br tag from mongodb data

Tags: html, mongodb, next.js

for my website using **Nextjs**, i want to display data from **MongoDB** database, and   in my data i use HTML tags like this: "From a world, <b>Cid Kagenô</b> try some..."

I tried to use return like this:

```html
<div className={styles.anime_body}>
        <p>
          {anime.synopsis}
        </p>
// more...
```

`anime.synopsis` return the good synopsis but like: "From a world, <b>Cid Kagenô</b> try some..." and not "From a world, **Cid Kagenô** try some..."

Comment: Maybe you want to read about React dangerouslySetInnerHTML